# What do you call a person who does not like to share things even though he/she has two or three of the same things?

Tags: single-word-requests

She has 5 headphones but she does not like to share even though we live under the same roof.

Comment: selfish ?   mean?

Comment: Very likely a *hoarder*.

Comment: I don’t share headphones even though I’m general pretty generous. I don’t share  headphones because I think of them as a personal item, so I’m too particular or even squeamish. Was headphones just a ‘for instance’, or is the question literally about headphones?

Answer (score 2):

That kind of person is - stingy. 
http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stingy
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stingy

Answer (score 2):

Words like "miserly" and "possessive" describe this trait in a person.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/miserly

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/possessive

Answer (score 1):

An apt term would be *penurious*. As the second definition in Merriam-Webster's dictionary shows:

> 2 : given to or marked by extreme stinting frugality (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/penurious).

However, the example given could be more a case where the person in question is simply paranoid, or 'grossed out', by the prospect of someone else's hair/oils/DNA what have you being in contact with their own ears after usage.

Comment: penurious to me implies that a person is unwilling to give because of penury, in other words aren't well off.

Answer (score 0):

self-serving

1. Serving one's own interests, especially without concern for the needs or interests of others.
2. Exhibiting concern solely for one's own interests

[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/self-serving)